# Mongodb Network Error unable to connect to database on first try

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm try to connect to mongodb atlas but however i get this here back.

MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [accounting-shard-00-01-6tg4q.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out]

```
mongoose
  .connect(
    "mongodb+srv://user:password@url.mongodb.net/accounting?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true
    }
  )
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected to Mongo database for testing");
    app.listen(8000);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

And the rest of the error is as follows

```
{ MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [accounting-shard-00-01-6tg4q.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out]
    at Pool.<anonymous> (/home/numbers/workspace/web/server/numbersServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:431:11)
    at Pool.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at connect (/home/numbers/workspace/web/server/numbersServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:557:14)
    at makeConnection (/home/numbers/workspace/web/server/numbersServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:39:11)
    at callback (/home/numbers/workspace/web/server/numbersServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:261:5)
    at TLSSocket.err (/home/numbers/workspace/web/server/numbersServer/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connect.js:286:7)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:286:20)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:442:8)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:436:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:300:5)
    at listOnTimeout (timers.js:263:5)
    at Timer.processTimers (timers.js:223:10)
  name: 'MongoNetworkError',
  errorLabels: [ 'TransientTransactionError' ],
  [Symbol(mongoErrorContextSymbol)]: {} }
```

Comment: You added your username and password to this script! You'll likely want to change them

Comment: One common issue with atlas is not adding your ip-address to the security whitelist.

Comment: I've added my ip-address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've also came across a certain error, turns out that my school by that time were blocking network requests to mongo, however when I used a vpn it work try it.